# Invoking Batchfile from Powershell with arguments throws error

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I have a simple batch file as below

```
set argument1=%1
set argument2=%2
echo Argument1 [%argument1%]
echo Argument1 [%argument2%]
pause
```

If I execute the below line from Powershell it works.

```
cmd.exe /c '"C:\test path\Sample.bat"  "C:\Program Files" "test2"'
```

Lets say now I store the batch file path in a variable and it fails.

```
$path = "C:\test path\Sample.bat"
cmd.exe /c $path '"C:\Program Files" "test2"' #This command fails
cmd.exe /c '$path "C:\Program F" "test2"' #This command fails

$arg1 = "C:\Program Files"
$arg2 = "testArg"
cmd.exe /c $path $arg1 $arg2 # This also fails
```

**Error thrown from power shell**

'C:\test' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I am doing some mistake, I don't know what's wrong. Could someone help me out with this?

Comment: This is due to the space in the path because you do not use quotes.

Comment: May I ask why you're not using Powershell instead of cmd for whatever you need to do? You're trying to run a command line shell from a command line shell. It's like putting a car inside of a car.  ;-)

Comment: @Olaf This is not true, batch files are not PowerShell syntax and require a different shell for execution, the car keys are different. If someone gives you the keys for a car then you know the keys work exactly for that car. You would not change the entire key to work for a different car, would you?

Comment: Per @bergmeister's initial comment: `cmd.exe /c '"$path" "C:\Program Files" "test2"'`

Comment: @bergmeister I did not say they are the same. I said they are both command line shells and it is unnecessary to start one with the other. Everything you can do with cmd you can do with Powershell ... and in the vast majority of cases easier and more powerfull.

Comment: @Olaf You meant to say we should use cmd.exe for invoking batch files. In that case, I used Start-Process way of invoking. That also doesn't work.

Comment: No. I wouldn't use batch files anymore at all. As I think, they are pretty much obsolete since Powershell exists.